# Does Bokeh's WebGL speed up heatmaps?

Tags: python, visualization, heatmap, bokeh

I have been reading a lot about Bokeh for visualisations of large datasets. I plan on plotting a heatmap with over 25 million points.

I saw read the [page](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/webgl.html) on speeding up WebGL and they mention that any plots with glyphs are accelerated.

Does the [Heatmap plot](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/heatmap_chart.html) use glyphs? Will there be any benefits in turning on WebGL for heatmap plots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much everything that Bokeh draws is a glyph of some type. However, the text on that page you link actually states that "allows rendering ***some*** glyph types on graphics hardware." Currently (as of Bokeh `0.12.3`) WebGL support only extends to scatter-type markers (e.g. `circle`, `x`, etc) and to lines. But `HeatMap` is implemented using the `Rect` glyph, so I would not expect WebGL to offer any improvement at the present time.

But I would add: It's good to thoroughly investigate any actual performance hotspots. Bokeh is really two libraries: a Python library and a JavaScript library. If you are seeing performance issues, are you sure it's on the JS side? For example, you have not said what your data sizes are. Are you sure it's not actually the binning/aggregation (that happens on the Python side) that is your issue?

Finally, if you have data sizes that are in the millions-to-billions of points range, you should probably be looking at the separate [bokeh/datashader project](https://github.com/bokeh/datashader).